# Help My Brother Work on his Tan(gent)!

Tags: geometry, brainfuck, metagolf

*This challenge is entirely fictional. There is no time limit for this challenge.*

My little brother is terrible with computers! He saved up all of his money to buy a new one, and within half an hour the hard drive was wiped and the only software left is a lousy BF interpreter. The worst part of it is, he has a huge Geometry test tomorrow and needs help!

## The Challenge

There's no way I'm going to let him touch my machine, so I'm going to need a fast way to write BF programs that solve his problem. He's learning about finding the area of regular polygons, and writing a new BF program for every calculation is a massive task. I need a fast way to generate BF programs! That's where you come in...

## The Input

Your program or function will receive an integer `2 < N <= 100` which shall represent the number of sides of a [regular polygon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_polygon). You may receive input from function arguments, command line arguments, STDIN, or your language's closest alternative. If necessary, you may additionally require trailing or leading whitespace.

## The Output

Your program should generate a separate [BF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck) program that takes input of a single positive integer `0 < a <= 10^10` that shall represent the length of the [apothem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apothem) of a regular polygon. When run, the BF program should output the area of a polygon with `N` sides and an apothem of `a`. More specifically:

- Assume that the BF interpreter is set up such that `,` takes a number as input and `.` outputs a value as a number, not a character. An input of `12` does not translate to the characters `'1' '2'` in memory, rather the literal number `12`. Similarly, when a value of `48` is output, it outputs `'48'`, not the character `'0'`.
- Assume also that each value on the tape of the BF program may contain an infinitely large **integer** -- the value will never wrap to 0.
- Assume that the tape of the BF spans infinitely to the right, but has no negative indices. The pointer starts at `0`.
- My brother is as careless with numbers as he is with computers. As such, the BF code should output the area **rounded to the nearest integer**.

## The Rules

In a separate and unrelated incident, my brother downloaded so much garbage onto my primary programming machine that I have virtually no hard drive space left. As such, your original program **may not exceed 512 bytes**.

Your score in this challenge is the length of all BF programs generated by your program for values of `N` from `3` to `100` inclusive.

[Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/standard-loopholes-which-are-no-longer-funny) are disallowed.

Comment: So, you don't allow him to touch your computer, but he somehow clugged up your computer with garbage? Maybe clean it up.

Comment: @Bálint If this is not humorous, then you're wrong. He might have installed all that garbage there *before* bying the new PC.

Comment: @EʀɪᴋᴛʜᴇGᴏʟғᴇʀ Don't worry, I was

Comment: @Bálint You were wrong or the comment was humorous?

Comment: @EʀɪᴋᴛʜᴇGᴏʟғᴇʀ The comment was humorous

Comment: @Bálint Typo + Spellchecker = MESS!

Answer (score 4):

### Python, 23938 score

```
from math import*
def apothem(n):
 c=int(n*tan(pi/n)/2*10)

 s=',>' + '+'*c
 m=">[-]>[-]<<[>>+<<-]>>[<<<[>+>+<<-]>>[<<+>>-]>-]<<"*2
 p=">>[-]<[-]<+++++<[-]++++++++++"
 d=">[>+<-]>[<<[>>>+>+<<<<-]>>>>[<<<<+>>>>-]<[>+<<-[>>[-]>+<<<-]>>>[<<<+>>>-]<[<-[<<->>[-]]+>-]<-]<<+>]"
 o="<."
 print s+m+p+d+o
```

- the area of a regular polygon is *nsa/2* width *n* given in Python and *a* later in BF. *s* is the sidelength of the polygon, which can be computed from *a* and *n*
- `c` is a constant, such that the area is *(aac+5)/10*, so only this formula must be coded into BF. *c* is between 15 and 25.
- `s` is the starting point for the BF code: read the apothem and write `c`
- `m` does *c=ca* twice, so in the cell formaly holding *c* there is *aac*
- `p` prepares for the final operation, clearing temporary cells, adding *5* to *aac* and setting the first cell to *10*
- `d` division
- `o` output

This is my first writing in BF, so all algorithms are from [this](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Brainfuck_algorithms) page.